# 'grep' or 'awk' for extracting numeric data from a file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a CFD output file containing alpha-numeric data. My goal is to extract certain rows having numeric data to be able to plot. I was able to extract data which starts with a numeric value using grep. However, some of the rows of this extracted data start with a number but contains alphabets also which i do not want. here is a sample

```
    3185 interface metric data, zone 1444, binary.

   33268 interface metric data, zone 1440, binary.

      3d, double precision, pressure-based, SST k-omega solver.

1  1.0000e+00  1.0163e-01  4.9782e-06  1.2250e-05  6.5126e-06  3.8876e+01  4.1845e+03  7.8685e+02  7.9475e+02  7.8234e+02  3.0537e+00  4.4427e+02 106:48:28 4999

2  1.0000e+00  6.5455e-02  1.4961e-04  2.2052e-04  1.3530e-02  6.8334e-01  4.5948e-01  7.9448e+02  8.0249e+02  7.9007e+02  1.3742e+00  5.7040e+02 92:12:06 4998

    4587 interface metric data, zone 2541, binary.

   6584 interface metric data, zone 1254, binary.

3  1.0000e+00  4.2029e-02  1.5227e-04  2.1588e-04  3.0255e-03  6.4570e-01  1.2661e-01  7.8044e+02  7.9048e+02  7.7804e+02 -2.3999e+05  6.4085e+02 80:35:24 4997

4  9.9121e-01  3.0808e-02  1.1390e-04  1.7132e-04  1.6542e-03  6.0594e-01  3.4626e-02  7.8613e+02  7.9673e+02  7.8422e+02 -1.9033e+05  7.0184e+02 70:56:41 4996
```

This is the command i used **grep -P '^\s*\d+'   file**. How can i modify grep command to give me last  rows with numeric data only ie

```
    1  1.0000e+00  1.0163e-01  4.9782e-06  1.2250e-05  6.5126e-06  3.8876e+01  4.1845e+03  7.8685e+02  7.9475e+02  7.8234e+02  3.0537e+00  4.4427e+02 106:48:28 4999
    2  1.0000e+00  6.5455e-02  1.4961e-04  2.2052e-04  1.3530e-02  6.8334e-01  4.5948e-01  7.9448e+02  8.0249e+02  7.9007e+02  1.3742e+00  5.7040e+02 92:12:06 4998
    3  1.0000e+00  4.2029e-02  1.5227e-04  2.1588e-04  3.0255e-03  6.4570e-01  1.2661e-01  7.8044e+02  7.9048e+02  7.7804e+02 -2.3999e+05  6.4085e+02 80:35:24 4997
    4  9.9121e-01  3.0808e-02  1.1390e-04  1.7132e-04  1.6542e-03  6.0594e-01  3.4626e-02  7.8613e+02  7.9673e+02  7.8422e+02 -1.9033e+05  7.0184e+02 70:56:41 4996
```

Comment: Not clear much, please clearly post samples along with efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 OP provided their attempt; it is `grep -P '^\s*\d+' file`, hard to see because it is one of the few things NOT formatted as code.... ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch, yeah right, but samples are still not clear honestly at  least to me it is not.

Comment: Bineet your question might get much clearer if you apply more helpful formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Also please provide an explanation of what failed in which way to work as desired with your coding attempt. (Ravinder I agree, as you can see.)

Comment: I did my best to format your post less distractingly. Please review, especially the leading white space and the asterisks. [edit] to get the appearance exactly as needed.

Comment: Bineet, please explain whether you really want the last 4 lines (see answer by KamilCuk) or which shape of line you actually want and maybe more or fewer and not necessarily at the end. Maybe all lines which start with blanks and an integer number *and another blank* ?

Comment: Also, what does your original data look like? Awk can probably function as your sole filter tool, without any pipes. Perhaps grep could as well, but we'd need to see the starting point.

Comment: Hi fish, so you think that the first code-formatted block is NOT their input data? Possible. Good question.

Comment: @Yunnosch, the OP did say "*I was able to extract data which starts with a numeric value using grep*", and gave us a `grep` command which matches ALL of the input data provided. So ya, that's my guess.

Comment: @ghoti Plausible. I admit that I cannot describe my understanding of the question as plausibly. I sitll believe that Bineet should give feedback on our speculations before I try to answer...

Comment: is there a way i can attach the file here.. will be more clear that way

Comment: @Bineet, we don't need your whole file, but perhaps you could construct a sample from it, not longer than your current input data, which contains examples of the patterns you want both to reject and to include. What you've shown us is not the problem, but a snapshot of your progress in trying to solve it. It sort of makes this an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 1):

> How can i modify grep command to give me last 4 rows only

Pipe the grep output to `tail`.

```
grep -P '^\s*\d+' file | tail -n 4
```

Comment: :-) Nice lateral thinking. But OP possibly meant "the lines which lead with blanks and an integer value" (which I think because otherwise the whole grep use seems useless). Your answer will helpfully provoke a statement on it - or be already what they want. Good either way.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the text in the question is the only thing we have to go on, I see a few patterns we might use to extract the last four lines.

The following matches lines whose first field is a number and contain no commas:

```
egrep '^[[:space:]]*[0-9][^,]+$'
```

This one matches lines containing numbers in scientific notation:

```
grep '[0-9]e[+-][0-9]'
```

And this one matches lines containing what looks like a time followed by an integer at the end of the line:

```
egrep '[0-9]+(:[0-9]{2}){2} [0-9]+$'
```

Or if you want an explicit match for the whole line -- that is, an integer, a number of scientific numbers, a time and then an integer, you can bundle it all together:

```
egrep '^[[:space:]]*[0-9]([[:space:]]+-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]+)+[[:space:]]+[0-9]+(:[0-9]{2}){2} [0-9]+$'
```

Note that I'm using explicit class names and ERE rather than shortcuts and PREG to maintain compatibility with non-Linux environments.

Comment: your solution "egrep '[0-9]+(:[0-9]{2}){2} [0-9]+$'" works very well,, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I think that everything in my answer is the wrong approach to solving this problem. :-)  I don't know what a "CFD" file is, but if it could be very long, or if you have a lot of them, you'll see performance increases by building your filtering into the processing. You can almost certainly do more of what you need in a single `awk` script, eliminating the need for pipes (and `grep`) altogether.

Comment: @Bineet, It is my humble request that always put samples in simple manner along with your efforts(though you had tried but it's not that clear honestly). People are egar to help and guide but we really expect from users to provide complete information to avoid confusions. Cheers and happy learning on this great site SO

Answer (score 0):

If your desired section of data can be identified by a certain header, e.g., the `3d,` before it, you can look for the header and only start printing matching lines afterwards, e.g.,

```
awk '/^\s*3d,/ { in_data=1; next } in_data && /^\s*[0-9]/' file
```

Here `/^\s*3d,/` is the pattern for the header which indicates the beginning of the "data section" (from the next line, i.e., not including the header itself). And `/^\s*[0-9]/` is the pattern for lines to print within the data section.

In case there is no such header, you could try to identify the first line of data itself with a more complicated pattern, e.g., the number of fields combined with a regular expression:

```
awk 'NF == 15 && /^\s*[0-9]*\s*/ { in_data=1 } in_data && /^\s*[0-9]/' file
```